# Shall we use react in our Microfrotnend having most of the modules in Angular?

Tags: reactjs, angular, http, structure, micro-frontend

I am changing my project to Microfrontend(having 15 modules). The older project is written in Angular.
I am thinking to create some modules in ReactJS. Will it create a better performance or not? Could you please answer it in respect of the performance scale?
Shall I continue to use Angular for all the modules or I should use some modules(say 2-3 modules) in ReactJS?

Comment: To be honest if your only concern is performance, I don't think you should switch to a new tool, but rather stick to the tool you know best. You can't have a general answer on whether React or Angular is more performant, it always depends on how you use the tool of your choice.